# Haskell. Why does read function does not work with custom data type though I used deriving?

Tags: haskell

Read function does not work properly with custom data type.

```
data TwoInts = Int Int
 deriving (Read, Show)

conv :: String -> TwoInts
conv s = read s
```

When i load this function with ghci
`ghci conv.hs`
It loads properly, but when i call it
`conv "15 14"`
i am getting following error:

`*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`

Comment: These are not two `Int`s: this is a data constructor named `Int` with one parameter: an `Int`. You can thus parse `conv "Int 15"` for example.

Comment: 1) Edit your question, don't write corrections in comments. 2) `data T = Int Int` contains _one_ int, only! The syntax is `data TypeName = ConstructorName Type1 ... `, and you chose `ConstructorName = Int` by accident. Write `data TwoInts = K Int Int` instead (you can use any uppercase name for `K`).

Comment: Thanks guys! That helped me. I should read more about read and data.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, your data type:

```hs
data TwoInts = Int Int
 deriving (Read, Show)
```

describes a constructor named `Int` that accepts a type `Int`. If you were to use records, maybe this is more clear:

```hs
data TwoInts = Int { int :: Int}
 deriving (Read, Show)
```

The solution as suggested in the comments is to name your constructor something else, e.g.,

```hs
data TwoInts = TwoInts Int Int
 deriving (Read, Show)
```